Phase Shift due to Total Internal Reflection
I am trying to derive the equation for the phase shift of transverse electric waves due to total internal reflection, but I can't make the final steps and it is driving me mad.
We start from the reflection coefficient for a transverse electric wave incident on a media interface $$r = \frac{n_1cos\theta_1 - \sqrt{n^2_2-n^2_1sin^2\theta_1}}{n_1cos\theta_1 + \sqrt{n^2_2-n^2_1sin^2\theta_1}}$$
and we end at the phase shift due total internal reflection $$\phi = 2arctan(\frac{\sqrt{sin^2\theta_1-(\frac{n_2}{n_1})^2}}{cos\theta_1})$$
It starts off easily: once $\theta_1>\theta_c$, $n_1sin\theta_1>n_2$ therefore $\sqrt{n^2_2-n^2_1sin^2\theta_1} = \pm i \sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}$, where we ignore the negative branch. Hence, $$r = \frac{n_1cos\theta_1 - i\sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}{n_1cos\theta_1 + i\sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}$$
By multiplying the top and bottom by the complex conjugate of the denominator, which is just the numerator, we get $$r = \frac{n_1cos\theta_1 - i\sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}{n_1cos\theta_1 + i\sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}.\frac{n_1cos\theta_1 - i\sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}{n_1cos\theta_1 - i\sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}$$
$$ = \frac{n^2_1cos^2\theta_1 - n^2_1sin^2\theta_1 + n^2_2 - i2n_1cos\theta_1 \sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}{n^2_1cos^2\theta_1 + n^2_1sin^2\theta_1 - n^2_2}$$
We know that this is a complex function with a magnitude of unity and an argument $\alpha$ which is $\phi/2$. We know that $tan\alpha$ is equal to the ratio of the imaginary component to the real component and so we can just ignore the denominator of the equation just above. Hence,
$$tan\alpha = \frac{-2n_1cos\theta_1 \sqrt{n^2_1sin^2\theta_1-n^2_2}}{n^2_1cos^2\theta_1 - n^2_1sin^2\theta_1 + n^2_2}$$
$$ = \frac{-2n^2_1cos\theta_1 \sqrt{sin^2\theta_1-(\frac{n_2}{n_1})^2}}{n^2_1cos^2\theta_1 - n^2_1(1-cos^2\theta_1) + n^2_2}$$
$$ = \frac{-2cos\theta_1 \sqrt{sin^2\theta_1-(\frac{n_2}{n_1})^2}}{2cos^2\theta_1 - 1 + (\frac{n_2}{n_1})^2}$$
This is as far as I get. Where have I gone wrong? How do I move forward?
